# Why is the next execution time of my Quartz trigger delayed by 8 hours?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, schedule, quartz

As you can see, I am building a scheduled task scheduler using Spring Boot and Quartz. Here is the core logic for generating Job and Trigger:

I have already included the Quartz Spring Boot dependency as follows:

```xml
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

Then I  defined a TimeJob class entity and saved it to the database using MybatisPlus

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@TableName("time_job")
public class TimeJob {

    @Null(groups = {Add.class},message = "不允许指定id")
    @NotNull(groups = {Update.class},message = "不允许指定id")
    @TableId(type = IdType.AUTO)
    private Integer jobId;
   
    @NotBlank(groups = {Add.class,Update.class},message = "jobName不能为空")
    private String jobName;

    @Null(groups = {Add.class,Update.class},message = "不允许指定time")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date createTime;

    @Null(groups = {Add.class,Update.class},message = "不允许指定time")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date updateTime;

   
  
    @NotBlank(groups = {Add.class,Update.class},message = "cron表达式不能为空")
    private String cronExpress;

    @Pattern(groups = {Add.class},regexp = "^\\[[1-9]+(,[1-9]+)*\\]$",message = "不符合数组规范")
    private String floorList;


  
    @NotNull(groups = {Add.class,Update.class},message = "startAt不能为空")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date startAt;

    @NotNull(groups = {Add.class,Update.class},message = "endAt不能为空")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date endAt;

   
    @NotNull(groups = {Add.class,Update.class},message = "enabled不能为空")
    private Boolean enabled;


    @NotNull(groups = {Add.class,Update.class},message = "UnitsId不能为空")
    private Integer unitsId;


    @Null(groups = {Add.class,Update.class},message = "不允许指定createBy")
    private Integer createBy;


    @Null(groups = {Add.class,Update.class},message = "不允许指定User name")
    @TableField(exist = false)
    private String createName;
}
```

Then I implemented an Http interface to store the TimeJob entity and add scheduled tasks to Quartz synchronously

```java
 @PostMapping("/job")
public CommonResult<String> addTimeJob(@RequestBody @Validated(Add.class) TimeJob timeJob) throws FloorFormatException, SchedulerException {
        int userId = StpUtil.getLoginIdAsInt();
        timeJob.setCreateBy(userId);
        timeJob.setCreateTime(new Date());
        timeJobService.saveJob(timeJob);
        return CommonResult.success("add success");
}
```

Here is the core logic of saveJob:

```java
 timeJobMapper.insert(timeJob);
 JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(PubRedisByteJob.class)
                .usingJobData("data",ByteUtils.byteArrayTo0xStringArray(data))
                .withIdentity(timeJob.getJobName()+":"+timeJob.getJobId().toString(),"PubRedisByteJob")
                .build();//执行
 CronTrigger  trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity(timeJob.getJobName()+":"+timeJob.getJobId().toString(),"PubRedisByteTrigger")
                .startAt(timeJob.getStartAt())
                .endAt(timeJob.getEndAt())
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(timeJob.getCronExpress())
                        .inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Shanghai")))
                .build();//执行
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail,trigger);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        log.info("next trigger time is {}",sdf.format(trigger.getNextFireTime()));
```

When I pass the following parameters:

```json
{
    "jobName": "test2",
    "cronExpress": "*/5 * * * * ?",
    "floorList": "[1]",
    "startAt": "2023-09-07 12:50:55",
    "endAt": "2023-09-08 12:50:55",
    "enabled": true,
    "remoteControlType": 1,
    "callUp": true,
    "unitsId": 26
}
```

I've already converted this JSON into a Java object named timeJob.

The content of the console output is:

```
2023-09-06 16:44:32.245 [][] INFO  o.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler:547 - Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2023-09-06 16:44:32.253 [][] INFO  c.t.RmsAdminApplication:61  - Started RmsAdminApplication in 4.991 seconds (JVM running for 5.516)
2023-09-06 16:44:39.460 [][] INFO  c.z.hikari.HikariDataSource:110 - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-09-06 16:44:39.669 [][] INFO  c.z.hikari.HikariDataSource:123 - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-09-06 16:44:39.709 [][] DEBUG c.t.m.TimeJobMapper.insert:137 - ==>  Preparing: INSERT INTO time_job ( job_name, create_time, cron_express, floor_list, start_at, end_at, enabled, remote_control_type, call_up, units_id, create_by ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
2023-09-06 16:44:39.730 [][] DEBUG c.t.m.TimeJobMapper.insert:137 - ==> Parameters: test2(String), 2023-09-06 16:44:39.456(Timestamp), */5 * * * * ?(String), [1](String), 2023-09-07 20:50:55.0(Timestamp), 2023-09-08 20:50:55.0(Timestamp), true(Boolean), 1(Integer), true(Boolean), 26(Integer), 12(Integer)
2023-09-06 16:44:39.732 [][] DEBUG c.t.m.TimeJobMapper.insert:137 - <==    Updates: 1
2023-09-06 16:44:39.751 [][] INFO  c.t.service.JobService:86  - next trigger time is 2023-09-07 20:50:55
```

I am suspecting if there might be an issue with Quartz's timezone configuration, but I don't have concrete evidence.

I have already tried configuring Quartz's timezone as "Asia/Shanghai" in both application.yml and the code, but it didn't solve my problem. What else can I try?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The problem is with the value of the start at and end at values (which are inserted as `2023-09-07 20:50:55.0(Timestamp), 2023-09-08 20:50:55.0(Timestamp)` according to your own log), so with those values, it will not start before `2023-09-07 20:50:55.0`. Seems somewhere between receiving the request, and storing it in the database, the wrong timezone is applied in some conversion of the parameters.

Comment: I've changed the description of problem and add a  minimal reproducible example,Based on your answer, I now tentatively confirm that this may be a problem with SpringBoot-jackson not specifying a time zone when receiving time parameters.

Comment: The problem is probably the use of `java.util.Date`.